# Eclipse CDT, environment variable for "name of file being currently compiled"

Tags: eclipse-cdt

I need to select some command-line parameters variable with name of file such as:

```
g++ [options] ${something}.s [other parameters] foo.cpp
```

to have assembly output same as foo.s for foo.cpp and bar.s for bar.cpp for all files of project.

Where can I find the necessary environment variable ${something}?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question. If you are compiling a cpp file, you can't have an assembly file as an input at the same time.

Are you trying to see the assembly file that the compiler generates for a cpp file? If so, add `-save-temps` to the compiler options and the .s file will be saved.

Comment: Only -save-temps enough to have all cpp files disassemblies?

Comment: perf seembs to be better at peeking relevant disassembly but needs program to run once at least.

Comment: `-save-temps` saved not disassembly, it saves the assembly source before it is assembled. So you do have to run the build to get it. If you want to see diassembly, use objdump on the .o or executable.