# Does std::shared_ptr have any effect over vectorization of a loop when used inside of that loop?

Tags: c++, g++, vectorization, shared-ptr

If I use shared_ptr instead of plain pointer in a trivial loop

```
// a is a shared_ptr
for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    a[i]+=1; 
}
```

can increment operation still be vectorized?

Comment: The only one who can obtain a definitive answer to your question is you, by looking at the compiled assembly code.

Comment: Actually I was trying that at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45402460/eclipse-cdt-environment-variable-for-name-of-file-being-currently-compiled but somehow eclipse doesn't let me know whats the file currently being compiled.

Comment: Why do you need your compiler to tell you "whats the flie currently being compiled"? You should already have a pretty good idea which file you are compiling.

Comment: I've meant cdt's internal makefile compiler thats compiling too many files like 50-60

Comment: So, even if there 50-60 files being compiled, you have no idea which file contains the code in question, whose vectorization you would like to investigate? How about opening each file and checking, or searching for the code you're looking for, then checking to see how it's compiled. Or how about simply writing a single .cpp file with the code in question, compiling it, and seeing what happens.

Comment: yes I can go terminal and use objdump command but I needed an instant-look option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `std::shared_ptr` generally only differs in behavior when you create/destroy them. [This operator (operator[]) is defined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_at) as having the same behavior as with a raw pointer.